# PySWMM: Access INP file without running a simulation

Tags: simulation

I have a model that I run (with the SWMM GUI), and I want to make some result analysis latter.

For that I need to get some data from the INP file. However, when I use

with Simulation(InpFilePath) as sim

the already existing report file gets overwritten.

Is there any workaround this issue?

I was expecting that the existing report file would remain untouched since I do not iterate over time inside simulation...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.